# Remote database connection using Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a Python programm which is scraping some values from my localhost. My aim is to store that values and to insert them into my live Website. To be more specific, i would like to insert those values into my live website database using my Python programm. The parser looks like that

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    import urllib

    x=urllib.urlopen("http://localhost/askisi2.html")
    s = x.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s)

    m = soup.find("div",{"id":"s_number"})
    id = m.text
    print id
```

Now from this point i would like to connect to my live database and insert the "id".How is it possible with Python to have access in my remote Database and what techniques should i follow?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use the [DB-API](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), and specifically for MySQL, [the `MySQLdb` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python). This is nonstandard, so you'll have to install it. First, you connect:

```
import MySQLdb
# other parameters are available; for details, see
# http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes
conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='someone', passwd='hunter2', db='some_database')
```

After you've connected, it's pretty simple to insert a row:

```
conn.execute('insert into some_table (id) values (?)', (id,))
```

When you're done with the connection, don't forget to close it.

```
conn.close()
```

Comment: Should i configure my live database first to allow external connections? The database is MySQL.

Comment: @Labrosb: If the Python script will run on the same server as the database, you do not need to configure the database to allow external connections. If it runs on a different computer, you will need to.